# I updated my phone using my husbands itunes acct. and now i've lost all of my contacts and pics and his are on my phone

Tags: itunes

I updated my phone using my husbands itunes acct. and now  lost all of my pics and contacts and his are now on my phone.  How can I get them back.  Doesn't look like I had mine backed up.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have were using your account before syncing with your husbands account, you probably would have your contacts backed up to the iCloud - under your account.

If that is the case

1. Go to settings and
2. Turn off syncing contacts to the cloud.
3. Save (nonexistent) contacts on the phone.
4. Back out of settings
5. Go back in and turn syncing contacts to the Cloud back on...

Here's a test to perform - using a computer's browser, log into icloud.com (using your Apple ID) and go to the Contacts page.  If they are gone, then they are gone.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I did not have my own itunes acct. prior to this.  I know my info has to be somewhere and will use your suggestions.

Comment: If you didn't already have your own account, the info is likely gone; you just overwrote it with another account.